# Breaking up a static string sql command into the command portion and seperate parameters

Tags: sql

I have a static string with parameters, being sent to an SQL Execute command.
The strings have the format of `delete 'Name' from table where x = 1 and y = 2` or `select * from table where x = 1 and y = 2`.
My problem is that I need to break the string into parameters.
How do I break the strings so that I can pass the command with the parameters to a single functional with the least possible work?
I have only one function to fix and handle this problem.

---

From this:

```
protected object ExecuteScaler(string queryString) 

{ OpenConnection(); } 

DbCommand command = _provider.CreateCommand(); 

command.Connection = _connection; command.CommandText = queryString; command.CommandType = CommandType.Text; if (_useTransaction) {

command.Transaction = _transaction; } 

try { returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar(); } ...
```

Can someone please give me an example?

Comment: How many strings like this do you have?

Comment: "I have a static string with parameters"  where? "being sent to an SQL Execute command" ohhh, I see, it is dynamic sql. Is it? "My problem is that I need to break the string into parameters" which are paremeters here? 1 and 2? please explain

Comment: Are you aware that `delete 'Name' from table` is invalid SQL?

Answer (score 1):

When you build a sql-command like this:

```
// don't do this because of sql injection
sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Col2 = " + somevalue;
```

Where you "break out of" the string constant to place a value, *that* is the point where you want to use a parameter placeholder:

```
// safe from sql injection
sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Col2 = @somevalue";
```

And then you can supply the value for `@somevalue` using the Parameters collection.

When the query needs some fixed values, then it is probably OK to keep them in the string:

```
// the "type" never changes for this query:
sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE type=1 and Col2 = @somevalue";
```